# How to free space in my / partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I created partitions to dual boot Kubuntu on my Windows laptop a few months ago. I have a 19 GB "/" partition that is already full. `apt-get clean` doesn't seem to help much. Other responses here have mentioned using GParted to add more space to "/", but it also seems like 19G should be enough space. Can I just move some root folders to my home directory?

After digging around `var/lib/docker` takes up 3.2G, and `/usr/lib/cuda-10.0` takes up 3.7G. How can I move these so applications I run can still find them?

```
➜  / df -h             
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.7M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb2        19G   17G  504M  98% /
tmpfs           7.9G   97M  7.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       256M   31M  226M  12% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb3       137G   21G  110G  16% /home
tmpfs           1.6G   16K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

```
➜  / sudo du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -h
0       ./dev
0       ./proc
0       ./sys
4.0K    ./cdrom
4.0K    ./lib64
4.0K    ./media
4.0K    ./mnt
4.0K    ./srv
8.0K    ./snap
16K     ./lost+found
20K     ./root
72K     ./tmp
1.7M    ./run
12M     ./sbin
13M     ./bin
16M     ./etc
195M    ./boot
201M    ./opt
891M    ./lib
4.4G    ./var
12G     ./usr
21G     ./home
37G     .
```

Comment: Your /usr is consuming 12G. Mine uses only 5G. Start looking there.

Comment: Myself I'd run into problems with 19gb.  It depends on what or really how much software you install on your system (*you need space when it comes time to release-upgrade etc*)

Comment: "but it also seems like 19G should be enough space"  That depends on the usecase so is highly personal. A NORMAL desktop will not go over 15Gb. A desktop used as a server will need a lot more if you keep the personal files on / and not elsewhere. I would suggest shrinking /dev/sdb3 and enlarge /dev/sdb2 " Can I just move some root folders to my home directory?" No. And please don't unless we are talking about personal files and you change the default location (like...  mysql has a setting to tell where to find the database).

Comment: @Kyle Safran Does this help? https://www.maketecheasier.com/clear-system-cache-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you most certainly can move these directories whereever you want. You just have to create a symbolic link. For example if you want to move /var/lib/docker to /home/var/lib/docker you have to create a link by executing

```
ln -s /home/var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker
```